# Why not speed up testing by using function dependency graph?

Tags: testing, integration-testing, functional-testing

It seems logical to me that if you have a dependency graph of your source code (tree showing call stack of all functions in your code base) you should be able to save a tremendous amount of time doing functional and integration tests after each release.

Essentially you will be able to tell the testers exactly what functionality to test as the rest of the features remain unchanged from a source code point of view.

If for instance you change a spelling mistake in once piece of the code, there is no reason to run through your whole test script again "just in case" you introduced a critical bug.

My question, why are dependency trees not used in software engineering and if you use them, how do you maintain them?  What tools are available that generate these trees for C# .NET, C++ and C source code?

Comment: Pex is obliquely related -- uses code analysis to generate tests based on possible code paths and possible parameter values. http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/

Comment: Manual testing? :-) Most things (even GUI) can -- and should -- have all the basic regression tests mocked up without a poor human clicking buttons. (And computer-time is relatively cheap.)

Answer (score 3):

The high-end versions of Visual Studio 2010 (Premium and Ultimate), in conjunction with TFS, provide such dependency analysis, called "impact analysis".

See "[Streamline Testing Process with Test Impact Analysis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff576128.aspx)" and 
"[Identifying Code Change Impact on Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264992.aspx)".

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be using some sort of continuous integration, especially if you have more than one developer, so that everything that has been saved in your source repository can be tested at least once per day to ensure that when everything is together to ensure that no new bugs have been introduced.

Seldom do I have changes where I fix a spelling mistake, as much as fixing actual bugs or adding new features.

But, you may be able to find what you want in VS2010, in the architectural tools(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2009/08/29/architecture-tools-in-vsts-2010.aspx), or in VS2008 this may be helpful: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/depgraph.aspx.

My problem with the VS2010 diagram is that to make it complete it gets too complicated to be of much use.

Ideally, if there was some way to pick one function, or a set of functions/classes, and have it highlight everything that would be affected, that could be useful, but only to help with some functional testing, as, your testers should still go through everything in case something else happened that will cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I do not agree with your assumptions. Your code has data dependencies in addition to the execution path dependencies. Let's say you have threads `A` and `B` running. `A` calls `a()` which does:

```
shared_memory.x.inc_by(2);
```

Thread B calls `b()`:

```
assert(shared_memory.x.value % 2 == 0);
...
```

And everything works fine (let's say ;) ). Then one day, you change the first function and do

```
shared_memory.x.inc_by(3);
```

instead for some reason. If you only check the functions depending on `a()`, you'll never get to test `b()` because it branched in some place - it might be even a dynamic callback.

This isn't limited to multithreading really - just chose it as an example. Every place that shares the data, or communicates with the outside world needs to be checked - which means "the whole program" really in the languages you listed.

It might be possible to do to some extent to do such analysis in some languages - either because of the lack of side effects, or because of some static analysis of the managed code - but in some cases (C/C++), you're not going to get any useful data out of it in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from visual studio there are many standalone source code dependency analyzers which can be used for that; [Source insight](http://www.sourceinsight.com/) is one such tool which provides dependency graph and visual call stack.

Answer (score 0):

That is very good idea, once you start having test cases that are more expensive (takes much time to run). Also, a good test suite might be spoiled just because nobody is running it, because developer don't have patience to wait for the runs.

Softagram is one standalone source code dependency analyzer that provides the information also for the test automation purposes. It analyzes all the mainstream languages such as Java, C, C++, C#, Python, PHP, JavaScript, TypeScript etc.

Currently there is a REST API that provides the information that is typically used in Jenkins scripts. With help of webhooks and centralized analysis set-up, Softagram can analyze automatically all the pull requests as soon as they appear or are modified, and also any unmerged branches, and the test automation has then as fresh as possible data available for selecting the impacted test cases.

It is also easy to write a script that will request the data from the analysis server for the developer environment use case. This makes unit testing much more feasible when you have huge amount of tests and want to find the errors even before pushing the changes forwards from your computer.

Current limitations are that Softagram analyzer cannot be installed to the developer workstation but is a server installation instead. It does not analyze side-effects. In dynamic languages it is hard to detect all the function calls correctly, so it is useful if you also have some #include/import statements in your code to make the analysis tool aware of your file to file dependencies.

Disclaimer: I am from [Softagram](https://softagram.com) and we use it ourselves for abovementioned purpose.